# I have a about iOS Block modifiers and scopes and need help. Description show in full code

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I did the experiment as shown in the figure, but I couldn't understand the result.

This is  my  full code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong) void (^DemoBlock4)(void);
@property(nonatomic,copy) void (^DemoBlock5)(void);
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Now is MRC, The copy shoudn't  Automatic.

    int a = 6;

//    //__NSStackBlock__ 
    void (^DemoBlock2)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"DemoBlock2 %d",a);
    };
    NSLog(@"DemoBlock2 %@",DemoBlock2);

    //__NSMallocBlock__
   // This is I executed it manually 'copy',[DemoBlock2 copy] is exactly the same as DemoBLock3
    NSLog(@"DemoBlock2.Copy %@",[DemoBlock2 copy]);

    void (^DemoBLock3)(void) = [DemoBlock2 copy];
    NSLog(@"DemoBlock3 %@",DemoBLock3);


    //But why self.DemoBlock4 is same __NSMallocBlock__? And I used the 'strong' modifier.
    //self.DemoBlock4 log is exactly the same as self.DemoBlock5(I user 'copy'),
    self.DemoBlock4 = ^{
        NSLog(@"%d",a);
    };
    NSLog(@"DemoBlock4 %@",self.DemoBlock4);

    self.DemoBlock5 = ^{
        NSLog(@"%d",a);
    };
    NSLog(@"DemoBlock5 %@",self.DemoBlock5);

}
```

This is Log:

```
    2018-11-30 13:02:35.170860+0800 blocktest[73540:8352045] DemoBlock2 <__NSStackBlock__: 0x7ffeea3b89f8>
    2018-11-30 13:02:35.170994+0800 blocktest[73540:8352045] DemoBlock2.Copy <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x60c00005eba0>
    2018-11-30 13:02:35.171102+0800 blocktest[73540:8352045] DemoBlock3 <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x60800004ec70>
    2018-11-30 13:02:35.171215+0800 blocktest[73540:8352045] DemoBlock4 <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x60c00005f680>
    2018-11-30 13:02:35.171320+0800 blocktest[73540:8352045] DemoBlock5 <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x60c00005f0e0>
```

So, as property **copy**(like [DemoBlock2 copy]) is automatic, even MRC?

And that makes **copy** and **strong**look the same.

I've read a lot about it and learned that Apple recommends using copy,
But I'd want to know more about what happens when different modifiers are used as property.
So I wrote this Dome.

Like this:

```
    @interface XYZObject : NSObject
    @property (copy) void (^blockProperty)(void);
    @end
```

[-fno-objc-arc ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZwGD.png)

Comment: As you note, Apple says “You should specify `copy` as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope.” So, I’d wager that if you use `retain` for block property in MRC that it will not correctly keep track of local vars captured by the block. You’ll likely have to experiment a bit to manifest the sorts of problems that Apple is warning you about.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `strong` vs `copy` semantics for block properties, you should use `copy` semantics (and in ARC, this happens automatically). See [Programming with Objective-C: Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12), which says:

> **Objects Use Properties to Keep Track of Blocks**
>
> The syntax to define a property to keep track of a block is similar to a block variable:
>
> ```
> @interface XYZObject : NSObject
> @property (copy) void (^blockProperty)(void);
> @end
> ```
>
> > **Note:** You should specify `copy` as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior. For more information, see [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in a direction. I checked the Apple documents. But the problem has not been solved. I found that my previous problem was not clearly described, so I adjusted the code and the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a very clear explanation of the semantics of the ARC modifier `strong` when used for properties in MRC, but it seems that in Clang, `strong` for properties in MRC means a retaining setter if the property has non-block type, and a copying setter if the property has block type. I found the [commit in 2011](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/6dc6f008994472cf4da321855e8c51c39720f3ed) in Clang that implemented this behavior.

So that's why your `DemoBlock4` is copied -- the property is a `strong` property of block type, for which Clang produces a synthesized setter that copies the block.

(Note that this is different from `retain`, which always means a retaining setter even if the property is block type. So if you change `DemoBlock4` from `strong` to `retain`, you will see that it prints `__NSStackBlock__` instead; and the compiler gives you a warning.)